# sqlite3 command-line - How to show less/more output

Tags: command-line, sqlite

I am using the sqlite3 command-line programme on Ubuntu.

I'd like to see its output paginated on the screen.

So for example, I'd start it like so :

```
 # sqlite3
 SQLite version 3.6.22
 Enter ".help" for instructions
 Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
 sqlite> _
```

Then, at the sqlite prompt, if I type `.help`:

```
 sqlite> .help
```

I see a long 'page' of help info, which comes to rest showing the final few lines on the screen.

I am not a fast reader and so cannot read all that info in just a few milliseconds.

So, how do I ensure that I only see a screenful at a time?

In normal command line parlance this could be piped to `| less` or `| more` but, that does not seem to work within this sqlite interactive shell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It does not seem to have something built-in.  However, you can use <kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd> to move up and down from different pages in a terminal (in Ubuntu is gnome-terminal by default, so that should work).

Also, you can call commands from the shell, like in:

```
$ echo .help | sqlite3 2>&1 | more
```

sqlite3 prints the output in `stderr`, therefore the redirection `2>&1`.  For SQL commands, you can use:

```
$ sqlite3 my.db "select * from my_table;" | more
```

And so on.

Answer (score 7):

From the [dbcli](https://www.dbcli.com/) collection the sqlite compatible [litecli](https://litecli.com/) emerged in 2018. It can use either the `$PAGER` environment variable or a defined pager in `~/.config/litecli/config`. As the util offers color support, I set it to `less -SniFXR`([?](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=less+-SniFXR)).

Another method is to let `sqlite3` write to an output file/pipe and use `less -f -S /tmp/sqlpipe` in a second terminal window or `tmux` pane to read it. Enable with

```
.shell mkfifo /tmp/sqlpipe
.output /tmp/sqlpipe
```

It will look like [this](https://asciinema.org/a/9eRmfRFCPTUxmwsEcLspwgMpR).

For not having to repeatedly enter the commands, a `~/.sqliterc` can be used to set them at startup. Further [formatting](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/219988/136169) improves the output, though in the end `litecli` is a much more comfortable solution.

Comment: I haven't attempt this, but +1 as it looks like a nice solution

Comment: @wbob testing on SQLite 3.34.1, and it freezes at `.output /tmp/sqlpipe` line!

Comment: @FaridCheraghi maybe a permission problem where you're not allowed to create a fifo in /tmp/ - if you're on macOS, I think there were some changes. The path where you create the named pipe is arbitrary, go with `~/.tmp-sqlpipe` maybe? I checked with 3.34.1 and added an [example](https://asciinema.org/a/KySDIMAuYVrhMv8qBhl1G4oAW?cols=150) how it's supposed to work. To be sure: it's a hack and cumbersome, needs tmux or two terminals

Comment: @wbob thank you very much for the screencast. I am on Debian though. I had made a mistake and created the named pipe with the SQLite parent shell process. I created the pipe with `.shell mkfifo pipe` and it solved it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sqlitestudio instead which sends output to a window with a scrollbar.  https://sqlitestudio.pl/index.rvt